# Sql entries to select

Tags: sql-server

I need values to appear per day even if there are no records

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Robotics.GetData
    @CelulaId INT,
    @Start DATETIME,
    @End DATETIME
  AS
  BEGIN

      SELECT 
        x.Date, 
        r.Shift, 
        r.Cell,
        r.Income
      FROM (
          SELECT x.Date
          FROM 
          (
              SELECT Date FROM DateDimension dd
              WHERE CONVERT(DATE, dd.Date) >= @Start 
              AND CONVERT(DATE, dd.Date) <= @End
          ) x
      ) x
      LEFT JOIN Records r
      ON x.Date = CONVERT(DATE, r.CreatedOn)
      AND r.Cell= '3.9.Y'    

  END
```

The problem is that i would like to show all available shifts per day even if there are no records for that shift on that day.

To get the days i have used Left join to a calendar table. This is my current result

```
Date        Shift   Cell    Income  
2019-09-13  Yellow  3.9.Y   100
2019-09-13  Blue    3.9.Y   200
2019-09-13  Green   3.9.Y   450
2019-09-14  NULL    NULL    NULL
2019-09-15  NULL    NULL    NULL
2019-09-16  Yellow  3.9.Y   200
2019-09-16  Green   3.9.Y   300
2019-09-17  Yellow  3.9.Y   250
2019-09-17  Blue    3.9.Y   100
2019-09-17  Green   3.9.Y   300
2019-09-18  Yellow  3.9.Y   200 
2019-09-18  Blue    3.9.Y   500
2019-09-18  Green   3.9.Y   750
2019-09-19  Blue    3.9.Y   250
```

I would like something like this to appear

```
Date        Shift   Cell    Income
2019-09-13  Yellow  3.9.Y   100
2019-09-13  Blue    3.9.Y   200
2019-09-13  Green   3.9.Y   450  
2019-09-14  Yellow  3.9.Y   0 // Null record
2019-09-14  Blue    3.9.Y   0 // Null record
2019-09-14  Green   3.9.Y   0 // Null record
2019-09-15  Yellow  3.9.Y   0 // Null record
2019-09-15  Blue    3.9.Y   0 // Null record
2019-09-15  Green   3.9.Y   0 // Null record
2019-09-16  Yellow  3.9.Y   200
2019-09-16  Blue    3.9.Y   0 // Null record
2019-09-16  Green   3.9.Y   300
2019-09-17  Yellow  3.9.Y   250
2019-09-17  Blue    3.9.Y   100
2019-09-17  Green   3.9.Y   300
2019-09-18  Yellow  3.9.Y   200
2019-09-18  Blue    3.9.Y   500
2019-09-18  Green   3.9.Y   750
2019-09-19  Yellow  3.9.Y   0 // Null record    
2019-09-19  Blue    3.9.Y   250
2019-09-19  Yellow  3.9.Y   0 // Null record


CREATE TABLE Shifts
(
    Id INT,
    Name NVARCHAR(20)
)

CREATE TABLE Cells
(
    Id INT,
    Name NVARCHAR(20)
)

CREATE TABLE Records
(
    Id INT,
    CreatedOn DATETIME,
    Shift NVARCHAR(10),
    Cell NVARCHAR(10)
    Income INT
)
```

Comment: Do you have a table that defines the list of shifts or is it a hard coded Yellow, Blue and Green? Do the shifts change over time?

Comment: Use a [Calendar Table](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/steps/bones-of-sql-the-calendar-table) and `CROSS JOIN` to your Shifts table (the one that lists the types of shifts you have, not the days they are on). That'll create a Cartesian product of all the dates and all the shifts. Then you can `LEFT JOIN` to your above table.

Comment: Cross join worked